# Spring Hibernate Integration using HibernateTemplate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am doing my first Spring + Hibernate integration example using HibernateTemplate in **Netbeans IDE**. Imported all the spring and hibernate related jars including **ojdbc14.jar**.

I have already created a table named **userstable** in Oracle 12G database that has same column names as that of attributes declared in my model/POJO class.

I have pasted below the main parts/warnings of the error in the Glassfish server window. The following are the errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT



Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT



Severe:   Startup of context /TestingMyGDPProject failed due to previous errors
Severe:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started


 Severe:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT



Warning:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT



 Severe:   Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT


Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT


Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /TestingMyGDPProject
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT] for bean with name 'ddd' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT
```

[Here is My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHpcC.jpg)

**Web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">



<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <!--<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>-->
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>registration.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>


  <context:component-scan base-package="Controller" />  
  <mvc:annotation-driven />  


                <!--VIEW RESOLVER-->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
      <property name="prefix" value="/View/"></property>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">     
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="system"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="Oracle_1"></property>  
</bean> 


<bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">            
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>      
        </props>  
    </property>              
    <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
            <value>resources/user.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
    </property> 
</bean>  


<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">              
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>          
</bean>     

<bean id="ddd" class="DataDAO.UserDAOImplementationHT">  
    <property name="ht" ref="template"></property>      
</bean>
```

**DAO Interface Implementation Class**:

```
package DataDAO;

import Model.User;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;


public class UserDAOImplementationHT implements UserDAO{

private HibernateTemplate ht;

public void setHt(HibernateTemplate ht) {
    this.ht = ht;
}

public UserDAOImplementationHT() {
}

@Override
public void registerAnUser(User newuser) {
    ht.save(newuser);
}    
}
```

**Service Layer interface Implementation class**:

```
package DataService;


import DataDAO.UserDAO;


import Model.User;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;



public class DataServiceImplementation implements DataService{



ConfigurableApplicationContext cap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

UserDAO daoob = (UserDAO) cap.getBean("ddd");             



@Override
public void registerAnUser(User newuser) {
   daoob.registerAnUser(newuser);       
}    
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class NewController  extends MultiActionController{


DataService dataservice;  



@RequestMapping("/register.htm")
public ModelAndView regUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException {          


    if(request.getParameter("regPassword").equals(request.getParameter("regConfrimPass"))){  
        String myDateFormat = request.getParameter("date1");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        Date dateofbirth = sdf.parse(myDateFormat);

        User newUser = new User(request.getParameter("email"),request.getParameter("regPassword"),request.getParameter("regFirstname"),request.getParameter("regLastname"),request.getParameter("regUniversityname"),Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("regPhonenum")),dateofbirth);                          
        dataservice.registerAnUser(newUser);

        return new ModelAndView("SuccessPage");
    }
    else {
        return new ModelAndView("FailurePage");
    }
}

}
```

could anyone please help me out in resolving this error? I have been trying to resolve by referring to several resources on the internet, but failed in every attempt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for project structure image. Sorry to ask but have you tried stopping the server, cleaning and building your project, start the server and then try to deploy the project again?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have done exactly the way you said. This time the project ran and I could see the registration.jsp page in my browser. But when I entered the details and submitted the form, I got the following error in my browser:    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: In the glassfish server window, I got this error:       Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Controller.NewController.regUser(NewController.java:52).  52nd Line in the Controller class:     dataservice.registerAnUser(newUser);

Comment: In this case you should check your NewController class e identify why you are getting a NullPointerException at line 52. My best guess is that your "regPhonenum" parameter at request is null, so when you try to long parse it you get an error. Also, i highly recommend you to look for some starter tutorials for Hibernate and Servlets, using a servlet to handle so many parameters to create a model object is not a good aproach.